# How to choose a linear model to conduct a Box Cox transformation in R

Tags: r, statistics, transformation

I am currently attempting to correct some data that I have. We have determined that they are not normally distributed and that a transformation is needed to assess the data. A Box Cox transformation was recommended to me, and it seems to be the best fit for my data.

When you perform a Box Cox transformation in R, you must run a linear model to pass to the Box Cox function.

`lm.model <- lm(x ~ a + b + c)`

`bc.model <- boxcox(lm.model)`

My question is about this linear model. What variables are necessary to go into this model? If I have variables **a** through **m**, do I just choose a subsection of them, or do all of the variables I intend to enter into my multiple regression go into the model? I have found that adding/removing variables does change the estimated lambda, but only by a small amount. It is possible that this choice is arbitrary, because one will end up rounding lambda anyway but I wanted to make sure.

Any info on this matter would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I think this is more suited for statsexchange

Comment: @chinsoon12 sorry I didn't know there was such a thing! I'll move the post over there now